# Calculating probability that two entangled qubits are the same when measured in different bases

Tags: entanglement, measurement, textbook-and-exercises, bell-basis

Given the entangled state

\begin{equation}
|\Phi^+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} |00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} |11\rangle
\end{equation}

I am trying to calculate the probability that the two qubits end up being the same when measured in different bases and getting different answers with 2 different methods.

**Method 1** is given by Section 2.2 p. 21 of [this](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Evazirani/f19quantum/notes/191.pdf) lecture note and reproduced below for convenience:

[image]

The answer according to this is $\cos^2 \theta$

**Method 2**: Consider the expected value of the product of the qubit spins (measuring qubit is technically measuring its spin).

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E[s_a \times s_b] & = (s_a \times s_b) \textrm{Prob}(s_a = s_b) + (s_a \times s_b) \textrm{Prob}(s_a \neq s_b) \\
                  & = +1 \cdot \textrm{Prob}(s_a = s_b) - 1 \cdot \textrm{Prob}(s_a \neq s_b) \\
                  & = p - (1 - p) \\
                  & = 2 p - 1
\end{split}
\end{equation}

which gives:

\begin{equation}
\textrm{Prob}(s_a = s_b) = \frac{1 + E[s_a \times s_b]}{2} 
\end{equation}

and $E[s_a \times s_b]$ turns out to be equal to $a_x b_x - a_y b_y + a_z b_z$ where $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are the axes chosen for measurement of the spins. See equation 11 in [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/bell-states-and-conservation-of-spin-angular-momentum/) for reference. I checked by hand and the formula is correct.

**Method 1 $\neq$ Method 2**. What gives?

Comment: why do you think that the expectation value of the product of the spins should equal the probability of them being equal?